# Find maximum value of array chunks minima (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, performance

I just did a HackerRank challenge, but my code kept failing 3 tests, with a timeout error. These tests were probably passing very large arrays as arguments (constraints said the arrays could have as many as 10<sup>9</sup> elements).

I researched some performance bottlenecks in my code (Array.slice, Math.min and Math.max, getting rid of unnecessary loops, etc) and optimized them all, but these tests were still failing. Is there a better way to approach this problem?

The statement:

Given an integer array `space` of length `n`, divide it into segments of size `x`, find the minimum value of each segment, then return the maximum value of all encountered minima.

Example:

```js
x = 2

space = [8, 2, 4, 6]

segments:
[8, 2]
[2, 4]
[4, 6]

minima: [2, 2, 4]

// Final answer: 4
```

Can't remember the constraints exactly but it was something like:
1 ≤ x ≤ n
1 ≤ n ≤ 10<sup>9</sup>
1 ≤ space[i] ≤ 10<sup>9</sup>

My code:

```js
function segment(x: number, space: number[]): number {
  let left = 0;
  let right = x;
  let max = 0;

  for (let i = 0; i < space.length; i++) {
    if (space[right - 1] === undefined) {
      break;
    }

    let localMin = Infinity;
    for (let j = left; j < right; j++) {
      if (space[j] < localMin) {
        localMin = space[j];
      }
    }

    if (localMin > max) {
      max = localMin;
    }

    left++;
    right++;
  }

  return max;
}

console.log(segment(2, [8, 2, 4, 6])); // 4
```

Comment: I have an inkling the problem is either misinterpreting the problem (statement) - please hyperlink the original - or not reusing (intermediate) results.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't post the link to the original problem because it's one of those company interview problems that are only accessible to candidates that receive the link by email. But I found a Stack Overflow question about the same problem, maybe it's better explained there:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66079780/time-and-space-complexity-of-the-max-disk-space

Answer (score 1):

I find it easy to spot the one problem with the code presented that can't be fixed without outside information:

It contains no "testable" specification, gives *no* clue as to what it is to accomplish. Use some accepted means of documentation - I've heard of JSDoc.

The approach I see taken in the code is *brute force*:
compute a summary information about multitudes independently from their elements - ignoring *large overlap*.
These problems are crafted to have *brute force* fail no matter the amount of force.

So after identifying the minimum of the first `x` items, what will be the minimum with "item 0 excluded and item x included"? Conceivably, that depends:
1) item 0 was the only item with minimum value
i) some other item is minimal
a) item 0 was minimum as well as others
I) item x is the new minimum
- never mind, the important takeaway is that the minimum changes "at the edges of the window", if at all.

So, what is *the most simple thing that might suffice*?
Take a look at i)&I): if the value wasn't the minimum, and the value entering it was larger, the minimum remains unchanged. (Try to asses the worst case performance of this.)
Then, there may be a suitable data structure for what's needed - spec it:
- report minimum
- remove by value/index in the input/"time" in the data structure
- add to the data structure
A balanced search tree(allowing for repeated keys) should fit the bill, there are bound to be better.

The code manipulates `i` without ever using it.
The loop is belt and braces, checking a limit *and* a termination condition: better use *either*
`while (space[right - 1] !== undefined)` *or*
`for (let left = 0 ; (right = left + x) <= space.length ; left++)`